# BottomSheet has no drag threshold when user initiates drag from within NestedScrollView

Tags: material-components-android

I'm using the [com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior) class from the com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04 lib and I've noticed that when a user initiates a drag on the BottomSheet it is treated differently depending on if the user drags from within a NestedScrollView versus outside of a NestedScrollView.

When a user starts dragging from a view that is a direct child of the BottomSheet view and then lets go, the BottomSheet will only collapse or expand if the user has dragged the BottomSheet past a certain threshold distance from it's original position.  If the user doesn't pass that threshold the BottomSheet snaps back to it's original position.

When a user starts dragging from a view that is a direct child of a NestedScrollView within the BottomSheet view (and results in the BottomSheet view moving) and then lets go, the BottomSheet will collapse or expand regardless of the distance the user has dragged the BottomSheet from it's original position.  There doesn't appear to be any threshold.

Is this the expected behavior?  Is there a way to get the BottomSheet to behave in the same way regardless of where the user initiates a drag?

Below are the files from my android project that result in the behavior described:

**activity_main.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Toggle Bottom Sheet" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**bottom_sheet.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bottomSheetBackground"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A TextView above the NestedScrollView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:text="A very tall button within a NestedScrollView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.bottom_sheet.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet_layout)

        btnBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
            if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
            } else {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!